# PostgreSQL query to group consecutive days of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a complex query and I am beginner in Postgresql.

Here is my schema with some sample data and **progress done so far**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8b13/35

In schema `no` column is just primary key.

My function takes argument `course_no`, execute the query and returns a json.

My query should do the following:

1. timeslots grouped by isodow, start time and end time.
2. consecutive week days grouped showing only first-last week day(like
   Mon-Tue or Mon-Fri)
3. Json ordered by start_timestamp so min(start_timestamp) is in the first group in json.

Example of a course_no with 47 timeslots all on Monday 11:00-11:45:

```
"[{"schedule":"Mon 11:00-11:45","count_timeslots":47}]"
```

A course_no with 15 timeslots on Tuesday 09:00-09:30 and 20 timeslots on Thursday 10:00-10:45:

```
"[{"schedule":"Tue 09:00-09:30","count_timeslots":15},{"schedule":"Thu 10:00-10:45","count_timeslots":20}]"
```

A course_no with 46 timeslots on Mon, Tue, and Wed 09:00-09:30 and 23 timeslots on Wed 17:00-18:00.

*NOTICE "Mon-Wed..."*

```
"[{"schedule":"Mon-Wed 09:00-09:45","count_timeslots":46},{"schedule":"Wed 17:00-18:00","count_timeslots":23}]"
```

I know how to extract time from timestamp and group by start_time and end_time, but I have no idea how to group by consecutive days?

**Update: Progress**

I wrote a query which COUNTS no of slots, GROUP BY start_timestamp and end_timestamp and ORDER BY min(start_timestamp).

I just need help to group them isodow(Days of Week) only when they are consecutive.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
count_timeslot, 
(EXTRACT(hour FROM start_timestamp) || ':' || 
EXTRACT(minute FROM start_timestamp)) AS start_time,     
(EXTRACT(hour FROM end_timestamp) || ':' || EXTRACT(minute FROM end_timestamp)) 
AS end_time FROM timeslot GROUP BY start_time, end_time ORDER BY MIN(start_timestamp);
```

**Update 2: Progress**

Almost completed this query with the help of window functions of Postgresql.

1. First I grouped them on the basis `start_time`, `end_time`, `day_of_week`.
2. Then I created `grp` by calculating `day_of_week - ROW NO() over partition of start_time` which gives me a constant value when they are consecutive.
3. Third I calculated SUM of `count_timeslot OVER partition of start_time and grp`.

My Query

```
SELECT *, SUM(count_timeslot) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) 
AS n_count_time 
FROM (
   SELECT *, day_of_week - ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY start_time ORDER BY day_of_week) AS grp 
   FROM( 
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_timeslot, 
     (EXTRACT(hour FROM start_timestamp) || ':' || EXTRACT(minute FROM 
     start_timestamp)) AS start_time, 
     (EXTRACT(hour FROM end_timestamp) || ':' || EXTRACT(minute FROM 
     end_timestamp)) AS end_time, 
     EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM start_timestamp) AS day_of_week FROM 
     timeslot GROUP BY start_time, end_time, day_of_week 
     ORDER BY MIN(start_timestamp)
     )foo
   )foo1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
WITH temp(k, v) 
AS(VALUES('Mon', 1), ('Tue', 2), ('Wed', 3), ('Thu', 4), ('Fri', 5), ('Sat', 6), ('Sun', 7))

SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(foo4)))
FROM(
    SELECT grouped || ' ' || start_time || '-' || end_time AS schedule
    , n_count_time AS count_timeslots 
    FROM(
        SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) AS row_no 
        FROM(
            SELECT * 
            , CASE 
            WHEN COUNT( * ) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) > 1 
            THEN first_value(name_of_day) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) 
                 || '-' || last_value(name_of_day) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) 
            ELSE first_value(name_of_day) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) 
            END AS grouped
            , SUM(count_timeslot) OVER (PARTITION BY start_time, grp) AS n_count_time 
            FROM(
                SELECT * 
                , day_of_week - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start_time ORDER BY day_of_week) AS grp
                , k AS name_of_day FROM(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count_timeslot
                , to_char(start_timestamp, 'HH24:MI') AS start_time
                , to_char(end_timestamp, 'HH24:MI') AS end_time
                , EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM start_timestamp) AS day_of_week 
                FROM timeslot 
                GROUP BY start_time, end_time, day_of_week 
                ORDER BY MIN(start_timestamp)
                ) foo, temp WHERE v = day_of_week) foo1
            ) foo2
        ) foo3 WHERE row_no = 1
    ) foo4;
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8b13/47